# In react native, I'm creating an app and get this warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm creating an app on React Native, and got this error below.
My app uses AsyncStorage, maybe is it the root cause?
Now my app has lots of codes, so I have no idea where I made it wrong...

What could be the cause?
It'd be nice if you could give me some advice on it.

```
 WARN  Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"88":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiSet"},"89":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiSet"},"90":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiSet"},"91":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiSet"},"92":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiSet"},"94":{"module":"Networking","method":"sendRequest"},"19645":{},"19661":{},"19677":{},"19693":{},"19709":{},"19725":{},"19741":{},"19757":{},"19773":{},"19789":{},"19805":{},"19821":{},"19837":{},"19853":{},"19869":{},"19885":{},"19901":{},"19917":{},"19933":{},"19949":{},"19965":{},"19981":{},"19997":{},"20013":{},"20029":{},"20045":{},"20061":{},"20077":{},"20093":{},"20109":{},"20125":{},"20141":{},"20157":{},"20173":{},"20189":{},"20205":{},"20221":{},"20237":{},"20253":{},"20269":{},"20285":{},"20301":{},"20317":{},"20333":{},"...(truncated keys)...":451}
```

Thank you in advance

App.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";
import toastConfig from "./App/config/toastSettings";

import phrases from "./App/data/phrases";

import navigationTheme from "./App/navigation/navigationTheme";
import AppNavigator from "./App/navigation/AppNavigator";
import FirstContext from "./App/context/context";

import savedData from "./App/utility/savedData";

export default function App() {
  // ===============================

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();

  // =====================================
  const [addedToX, setAddedToX] = useState(phrases);
  const [choseNumFromX, setChoseNumFromX] = useState("");
  const [showXPhrases, setShowXPhrases] = useState(true);
  const [showAllPhrases, setShowAllPhrases] = useState(false);
  const [showBoth, setShowBoth] = useState(true);
  const [hideEng, setHideEng] = useState(false);
  const [hideJp, setHideJp] = useState(false);
  const [visibleEng, setVisibleEng] = useState(false);
  const [visibleJp, setVisibleJp] = useState(false);
  // const [filteredList, setFilterdList] = useState(
  //   phrases.filter(({ id }) => addedToX.includes(id))
  // );
  const PERSISTENCE_KEY = "NAVIGATION_STATE_V1";

  //For saving checkedForAddedToX
  // ======== ===========================================

  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.getShowXPhrases(setShowXPhrases);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showXPhrases !== null) {
      savedData.saveShowXPhrases(showXPhrases);
    } else {
      setShowXPhrases(true);
    }
  }, [showXPhrases, showAllPhrases]);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.getShowAllPhrases(setShowAllPhrases);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAllPhrases !== null) {
      savedData.saveShowAllPhrases(showAllPhrases);
    } else {
      setShowAllPhrases(false);
    }
  }, [showAllPhrases, showXPhrases]);

  // For saving options
  // ==========================================================

  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.getShowBoth(setShowBoth);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showBoth !== null) {
      savedData.saveShowBoth(showBoth);
    } else {
      setShowBoth(true);
    }
  }, [showBoth, hideEng, hideJp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.getHideEng(setHideEng);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hideEng !== null) {
      savedData.saveHideEng(hideEng);
    } else {
      setHideEng(false);
    }
  }, [showBoth, hideEng, hideJp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.getHideJp(setHideJp);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hideJp !== null) {
      savedData.saveHideJp(hideJp);
    } else {
      setHideJp(false);
    }
  }, [showBoth, hideEng, hideJp]);

  //For saving addedToX
  // ======== ===========================================
  useEffect(() => {
    savedData.retrieveState(setAddedToX);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (addedToX !== null) {
      savedData.saveState(addedToX);
    } else {
      setAddedToX(phrases);
    }
  }, [addedToX]);

  // // ==========================================================
  // For starting the app with the screen that the user last visited.
  useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
      try {
        // const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
          const savedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);
          const state = savedState ? JSON.parse(savedState) : undefined;

          if (state !== undefined) {
            setInitialState(state);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReady(true);
      }
    };

    if (!isReady) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }
  // ============================================================
  return (
    //We just have to wrap pages in <NavigationContainer>
    //theme is like a default setting for say styling that's from react.
    // <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>

    <FirstContext.Provider
      value={{
        addedToX,
        setAddedToX,
        showXPhrases,
        setShowXPhrases,
        choseNumFromX,
        setChoseNumFromX,
        showAllPhrases,
        setShowAllPhrases,
        showBoth,
        setShowBoth,
        hideEng,
        setHideEng,
        hideJp,
        setHideJp,
        visibleEng,
        setVisibleEng,
        visibleJp,
        setVisibleJp,
      }}
    >
      <NavigationContainer
        initialState={initialState}
        onStateChange={(state) =>
          AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state))
        }
      >
        <AppNavigator />
        <Toast config={toastConfig} />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </FirstContext.Provider>

    // <Test />
  );
}
```

Here, a file that's related to saving to AsyncStorage

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

//For saving addedToX
// ===============================================

const retrieveState = async (setAddedToX) => {
  try {
    const savedaddedToX = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@addedToX");

    setAddedToX(JSON.parse(savedaddedToX));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

// const retrieveState = async (setAddedToX) => {
//   const savedaddedToX = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@addedToX");

//   setAddedToX(JSON.parse(savedaddedToX));
// };

const saveState = async (addedToX) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@addedToX", JSON.stringify(addedToX));
};

//For saving options for chosing all or X
// =====================================================

const getShowXPhrases = async (setShowXPhrases) => {
  try {
    const savedShowXPhrases = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@showXPhrases");
    setShowXPhrases(JSON.parse(savedShowXPhrases));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const saveShowXPhrases = async (showXPhrases) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@showXPhrases", JSON.stringify(showXPhrases));
};

const getShowAllPhrases = async (setShowAllPhrases) => {
  try {
    const savedShowAllPhrases = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@showAllPhrases");
    setShowAllPhrases(JSON.parse(savedShowAllPhrases));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const saveShowAllPhrases = async (showAllPhrases) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@showAllPhrases", JSON.stringify(showAllPhrases));
};

//For saving three options, hide or not
// ======================================================================

const getShowBoth = async (setShowBoth) => {
  try {
    const savedShowBoth = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@showBoth");
    setShowBoth(JSON.parse(savedShowBoth));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const saveShowBoth = async (showBoth) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@showBoth", JSON.stringify(showBoth));
};

const getHideEng = async (setHideEng) => {
  try {
    const savedHideEng = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@hideEng");
    setHideEng(JSON.parse(savedHideEng));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const saveHideEng = async (hideEng) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@hideEng", JSON.stringify(hideEng));
};
const getHideJp = async (setHideJp) => {
  try {
    const savedHideJp = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@hideJp");
    setHideJp(JSON.parse(savedHideJp));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const saveHideJp = async (hideJp) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("@hideJp", JSON.stringify(hideJp));
};

// ======================================================================

export default {
  retrieveState,
  saveState,
  // clearAll,
  getShowXPhrases,
  saveShowXPhrases,
  getShowAllPhrases,
  saveShowAllPhrases,
  getShowBoth,
  saveShowBoth,
  getHideEng,
  saveHideEng,
  getHideJp,
  saveHideJp,
};
```

Comment: Okay, I put some of my files.

Comment: I would reduce the number of useEffects, or at least prevent duplicate ones. This one for example: `useEffect(() => {..}, []);` should be defined only once per component.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I want to try that. But each of the functions using useEffect is called depending on the condition, which is in ([]). If I put them together into only one useEffect, won’t the conditions that cause to call the functions mix up?

Comment: If you mean the arguments provided in the array, at the end of the useEffect, then yes. But you do have some duplicates with the exact same arguments.

Comment: Ah yeah I got it! I think I should first try to reduce the duplicates like you suggest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give definitive answers without seeing any code, but if you have any async or promise based functions within a useEffect(), that can overload the app pretty quickly.

There's a few other posts asking about similar issues, and the answers commonly recommend using [Promise.all from the bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html). Most importantly though would be identifying where you're calling an async function or returning a Promise within a useEffect() or something that runs at a similarly high frequency.

Comment: I put some of my files. Hmm, async functions within a useEffect...that's what I do here I guess?